# Bitter Turnip fries

Tags: substitutions, potatoes, low-carb, keto

I tried making turnip fries the other day and they were horribly bitter. If  am planning to fry them like french fries how long should I boil them in the salt, vinegar and lemon juice so that they don't get too mushy? I have never prepared turnips as a potato before.Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [cooking.se]!  **;-)** It's quite clear what the problem is, but *for the future* could you please describe more clearly what you're doing exactly: I can deduce you're trying to parboil the turnips, but I wouldn't: I'd just cut them up in smaller (McDonald's size) fries and soak them overnight in as little water as possible as per the answer...  **0:-)**

Comment: Sure, I just saw this solution of parboiling them from someone else. I will certainly try and be clearer next time. So nothing in the water or follow Fabby's suggestion with as little water as possible? I thinly sliced them when I tried to prepare them Friday just slice and fry and that did not work out well at all.

Comment: So? How did the Gin&Turnip turn out? (or keeping it for next time?) **;-)**

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, I need to by some gin, I only have Crown Royal at home, I think that is brandy? Not sure, it's my husbands thing. :-) I had a bout with declining health for one day... not enough electrolytes I assume because as soon as I got some in me I was A-OK. Needless to say, I slept all day and all night Tuesday.

Comment: Angela, did you ever get a chance to try??? (Just got another upvote on this today and still wondering...)  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

First of all: you made me laugh because I misread the title as "Bitter *Trump* Fries"...  **:D**

Secondly: if they're too bitter, there are a few things you can do by soaking them overnight in the fridge with water with *one of the following*:

- a dash of honey (take warm tap water and let it cool down after you've added the honey)
- a dash of lemon (or better: lime) juice
- a dash of gin

*How much is "a dash"?*
Well, for 500g / a pound of turnip: a coffee spoon or maximum 2 depending how bitter they taste raw.

Comment: Thank you Fabby I will try this. I am really missing french fries since I have been low-no carb. I really wanted to curb this desire.

Comment: @AngelaJohnsonAppy I'm just a midget here: please wait a while because maybe some of the giants here on the site will come up with an even better idea! And if you're trying no-carb: *skip the honey.* For low-carb: use half a dash!  **;-)**

Comment: I was going to try the gin, actually. :-) Thanks I will give it some time.

Comment: Well... I put that one last, but ...  **;-)**